# Dividir por numero iguales

Tags: javascript, swift, algoritmos

quiero obtener una matriz de vectores con contenidos iguales: por ejemplo 
tengo esta entrada: [1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,6] el resultado esperado que quiero es: [[1,1],[2,2,2],[3],[4],[5,5],[6]]

```js
let arr = [1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,6]
let resCopy = []
let resTotal = []
let visited = []

for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {

            resCopy.push(arr[i])
            if(visited.indexOf(arr[i])==-1){
                visited.push(arr[i])
                
                    resTotal.push(resCopy)
                    resCopy=[]
                
            }
        }
        console.log(resTotal)
```

quisiera pasarlo a lenguaje swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo si los elementos estan ordenados, puedes recorrer el array con `.reduce()` y verificar si el último elemento (también array) del array temporal incluye al actual valor, si ese el caso lo agregas, sino creas otro elemento (array) solo con el elemento actual.

```js
let arr = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6];

const res = arr.reduce((p, c, i) => {
  if (p.length && p[p.length - 1].includes(c)) {
    p[p.length - 1].push(c);
  } else {
    p.push([c]);
  }
  return p;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: No conozco swift, pero supongo que hay que reemplazar el .reduce y el .includes, que en definitiva son dos loops.  Porque no deben existir, al menos con esa sintaxis en swift.

Comment: sintaxis corta: `const res = arr.reduce((p, c) => (n=p.length,( n && p[n -1].includes(c)) ? p[n - 1].push(c) : p.push([c]), p ) ,[]);`